# Load a product by name is not working in magento?

Tags: magento

I have the following code to load a product in magento using **Name**.

```
$pro = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('name', 'test simple product3');
print_r($pro->getData());
```

But after executing this I am getting error as follows

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object
>   in .....

The product `test simple product3` exist...

What might be the reason for this and what is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are calling is perfect. I think there has to be some mistake in writing the product name. Try for some other product and check. It will give error only when  the product name you have mentioned is not exact like it is present in magento.

Comment: Please check first your product exist in your list or not. i think product not available in your list.